# How can I detect ffmpeg vs libav in CMake?

Tags: ffmpeg, cmake

My project uses libavformat to connect to `rtsp://` URLs. It's important that it set a socket timeout and reconnect on error. Unfortunately, the `stimeout` open option for this only exists in [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) (and in particular, its libavformat versions >= 55.1.100), not the competing project [libav](http://libav.org/) (any version). And some systems I'd like to support (such as Raspbian Jessie) are still bundled with libav.

So, I think my best option is to detect whether I have a suitable version using cmake, and install ffmpeg in-tree if not. I think I should be able to do this via something like:

```
pkg_check_modules(FFMPEG libavutil libavcodec libavformat)

if(not FFMPEG_FOUND or FFMPEG_VERSION VERSION_LESS 55.1.101)
  ExternalProject_Add(
    FfmpegProject
    URL "http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-2.8.3.tar.xz"
    URL_HASH "SHA1=a6f39efe1bea9a9b271c903d3c1dcb940a510c87"
    INSTALL_COMMAND "")
  ...set up flags and such to use this in-tree version...
endif()
```

except that I don't know how to detect libav vs ffmpeg. I don't see anything in the pkgconfig stuff or `libavformat/version.h` to distinguish them. The version numbers they use seem to overlap. It's not obvious to me at all how to tell the difference programmatically, much less do so with a not-weird cmake rule. Any ideas?

Comment: You can run `ffmpeg` and use `stimeout` there to see if it supports it.

Comment: @arrowd Not sure the library I'm using would be the same as what ffmpeg is using, for one thing. I'd like to reliably detect what I'm actually using.

Comment: I guess one possibility is to write a program that calls `avformat_open_input` and returns error if the `stimeout` is still left in the `options` dict afterward (meaning it was ignored). It could use some bogus URL that will always fail quickly, like maybe "rtsp://0.0.0.0:0/". I guess cmake has this [try_run](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/try_run.html) construct for doing something like that.

Comment: or better, [check_c_source_runs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/CheckCSourceRuns.html)

Comment: By looking at rtsp.c patch that added this option, i thought it wasn't possible to programmatically check its presense. If i'm mistaken then yes, you can use `check_c_source_runs`.

Comment: Ehh, no good. avformat_open_input says about dict "On return this parameter will be destroyed and replaced with a dict containing options that were not found. May be NULL", but the mutation doesn't happen if the connection fails. I don't want to set up a real RTSP server for this test; that's way too much work... so I think I'm back to some other way to detect libav vs ffmpeg.

Comment: A wild guess - you can `grep` binary library file for `"timeout (in micro seconds) of socket i/o operations."` string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To specifically answer your question, use this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "libavutil/opt.h"
#include "libavformat/avformat.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    av_register_all();
    AVInputFormat *input = av_find_input_format("rtsp");
    const AVClass *klass = input->priv_class;
    const AVOption *opt = av_opt_find2(&klass, argv[1], NULL, 0, AV_OPT_SEARCH_FAKE_OBJ, NULL);
    printf("%p\n", opt);
    return 0;
}
```

This can do runtime detection, and here's how it works:

```
bash-3.2$ /tmp/test hi
0x0
bash-3.2$ /tmp/test stimeout
0x103420100
```

For your other question, detecting Libav vs. FFmpeg can be done by looking at the library micro version. For FFmpeg, they all start at 100 (e.g. libavformat 55.1.100), whereas for Libav, they start at 0. So if micro < 100, it's Libav, else it's FFmpeg. To get libavformat micro version at runtime, use [avformat_version()](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.8/libavformat_2version_8h.html#a3224be1c325e29c7ed5c1f69f5a4d343) & 0xff, or [LIBAVFORMAT_VERSION_MICRO](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.8/libavformat_2version_8h.html#a3224be1c325e29c7ed5c1f69f5a4d343) at compile time.